# How to add label over another label in java?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I have a project in which I have added an image throuh `JLabel` which is my background image. Now I want to add a transparent image through `JLabel` image which has got some text over it. When I am adding my image over the background image it is disappearing. How to achieve it?

Here is the code of 2 labels **lmain** is the name of background image label and **lblNewLabel** is the name of the text image label.

```
JLabel lmain = new JLabel("");
lmain.setBounds(0, 0, 1600, 900);
pmain.add(lmian);
lmain.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Raabii Ansari\\Desktop\\k3.jpg"));

JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
lblNewLabel.setBounds(502, 69, 498, 232);
lmain.add(lblNewLabel);
lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Raabii Ansari\\Desktop\\text (4).gif"));
```

Comment: Well, `JLabel` is just a `Container`, you could just add one label into another, possibly even using a layout manager, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115320/having-a-jlabel-on-top-of-another-jlabel-that-has-an-image/33115415#33115415) for example.  Not my preferred method, but it will generally work

Comment: See also this [related approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513).